# In R, website read with read_html is redirected. How to get the url that it was redirected to?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

```
this_page = read_html("https://apu.edu/athletics")

> this_page
{xml_document}
<html id="ctl00_html" lang="en" class=" index homepage">
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<script>window.client_hostname = "athletics.apu.edu";window.server_name = "79077 ...
[2] <body>\n<div style="position: fixed; left: -10000px"><script src="//cdn.blueconic.net/azusa.js" async=""></script></div>\n<script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[ ...
```

although we read `https://apu.edu/athletics`, it redirects to `athletics.apu.edu`. This is true both in the browser, and it can also be seen in the output of `this_page` right here: `<script>window.client_hostname = "athletics.apu.edu"; ...`

Is it possible to extract this value out of the `this_page` variable?

**Edit:** the currently top 3 answers (ekoam, David, Allan) all work, and all take ~ the same amount of time (0.35 seconds). I've accepted the answer with `trace_redirects` because it provides the addt'l info of all the redirects...

Comment: Not sure if `rvest` can do this. It should be possible using `selenium`, see [this](https://cran.uni-muenster.de/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html) for getting started.

Comment: Why not just `read_html("https://athletics.apu.edu")`?

Comment: @ekoam I am provided with a long list of URLs. `apu.edu/athletics` is provided but `athletics.apu.edu` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the redirects (you are actually redirected twice here), you can use this function:

```r
trace_redirects <- function(url) {
  httr::GET(url)$all_headers %>%
    lapply(function(x) x$headers$location) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    unique()
}
```

So you can do:

```r
trace_redirects("https://apu.edu/athletics")
#> [1] "https://www.apu.edu/athletics" "http://athletics.apu.edu"      
#> [3] "https://athletics.apu.edu/"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using `httr` for this, then just:

```
httr::GET("https://apu.edu/athletics")[["url"]]

> httr::GET("https://apu.edu/athletics")[["url"]]
[1] "https://athletics.apu.edu/"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `html_session()` instead, it should work:

```r
library(rvest)

url <- "https://apu.edu/athletics"
s <- html_session(url)
s
#> <session> https://athletics.apu.edu/
#>   Status: 200
#>   Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
#>   Size:   221620

s$url
#> [1] "https://athletics.apu.edu/"
```

Comment: this looks promising